# What is Jason Bourne's fighting style called

Tags: technique

What fighting style does the character 'Jason Bourne' played by Matt Damon in the 'Bourne Series' use?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This contains one good question (+1) and one terrible one (-1).  The former is the the first sentence. The latter is the second one referring to effectiveness.  That question solicit arguments, cannot be answered objectively, and solicit a list classification. All those are frowned upon -- see the [FAQ](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: In addition, a quick [Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=bourn+martial+art&oq=bourn+martial+art&sugexp=chrome,mod=11&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) will give you the answer...

Comment: Just a note - The google search that Sard references is what they used for the movies, so that is the Hollywood interpretation. The books were written long before the movies, so that may or may not be what you were looking for.

Comment: @JohnP: Indeed it is but that's what the question is asking.

Comment: @Sardathrion - Could be interpreted either way, was just clarifying.

Comment: I read the first three books years ago. I don't remember any reference to a particular style and the movies differ strongly from the books (disappointingly so in my opinion, good action movies but would still have like to see the original book stories).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Believe it or not, you're actually seeing Jeet Kune Do (which was adapted to look more visually spectacular). Jeff Imada, who was the chief choreographer for the films studied JKD with no-one other than Brandon Lee. The knife techniques are actually his own. He spent a long time developing techniques with the butterfly knife and even published two books on it.

I should probably clarify: Jeff Imada and Brandon Lee both studied under Dan Inosanto, as opposed to Brandon being Jeff's teacher.

Answer (score 4):

Bourne's techniques come from a mix of Escrima/Kali and JKD, which makes sense, considering the martial arts consultant. It is most assuredly *not* straight JKD, but Sijo Bruce influenced Guro Dan, and Guro Dan influenced Sijo Bruce.

- Source 1: Jeff Imada, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XCCFBNV--o
- Source 2: My instructor, Guro Rick Tucci, Full Instructor under Guro Dan.

Comment: Explanations regarding downvotes are generally appreciated. I'm not sure how you could get much more accurate than hearing it from the man's own mouth.